# delete and refresh in recyclerview

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, bottomnavigationview

In my app I have a bottom navigation including home and favorites. in the recyclerview when I click on like button it'll be added to favourites. now when clicked again, I want to remove it from favorite at the moment.

In my code the item is deleted but it won't be removed until I go to home and return.

Note that I can't use `arraylist.remove(position)` because if so, even in home fragment the item is removed and I don't want that.

code in adapter:

```
itemHolder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int rowId = databaseHelper.GetId((String) itemHolder.headline.getText().toString());
                if (databaseHelper.IsLiked(rowId)){
                    databaseHelper.UpdateLiked(rowId, false);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                }
                else{
                    databaseHelper.UpdateLiked(rowId, true);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yourarraylist.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, yourarraylist.size());
```

Comment: try this

yourarraylist.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, yourarraylist.size());

Comment: as I said in the question I can't use arraylist.remove(position) because if I do it, even in the home fragment when I unlike the item, it will be removed from list, which shouldn't happen

Comment: is there a way to say if you're on favorite fragment then yourarraylist.remove(position) ?

Comment: yes, you create and interface and then you remove from fragment

Comment: If you are using same arrayList for HOME and FAVORITE, then you can not remove from only one place. It will be removed from both places. for that, you have to maintain 2 columns in database, such as home = true/false and favorite = true/false. This way you can set true or false for HOME and FAVORITE. If value is false, you don't show the item. If it is true, You can show it. i hope it helps! please upvote if this help you.